# Visual Studio Tabular Model to Data Lake

Tags: azure-data-lake, ssas-tabular

How can create a tabular model over Azure Data Lake?

I am able to create the Power BI Model with Azure Data Lake and upload it to the Azure Analysis Server. But, I need to create a tabular model over Azure Data Lake.

When I check the data sources, I don't see Azure Data Lake. I see it in Power BI Get Data.

Comment: [Azure Data Lake Store should be supported in Azure Analysis Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/analysis-services/analysis-services-datasource). Are you sure you created a Compatibility Level 1400 model? Also, are you sure you're using Power Query (structured) data sources, and not legacy?

Answer (score 2):

You need to select Compatibility level SQL Server 2017/ Azure Analysis Services (1400) and then you will have ADLS in data sources.

Comment: How do I see this compatibility level. I can't see it in my Visual Studio 2015, but my colleague can see it.I can see the previous versions only.

Comment: Sounds like you have to install a [newer version of SSDT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt?view=sql-server-2017#ssdt-for-vs-2015-standalone-installer) for Visual Studio.